# Frame Processor threw an error: Value is undefined, expected an Object

Tags: react-native

In react native Project i installed react-native-vision-camera and react-native reanimated and then react-native-hole after running the project it gives me the error   Frame Processor threw an error: Value is undefined, expected an Object
though camera is opened but it comes repeatedly the error, Please help to overcome the solution...i want to make the QR Code Scanner ...the react native QRScanner is getting deprecated please help for making QR Scanner in React Native ..Please help

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by following these steps-

1. Change in your babel config-

> ```
>   module.exports = {
>   presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
>   plugins: [
>     [
>       // <-- this
>       'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
>       {
>         globals: ['__scanCodes'],
>       },
>     ],
>   ],
> };
> ```

2. `npm start -- --reset-cache`
3. add  `import 'react-native-reanimated';` at the top on `index.js` file